# Java TimeZone update

Tags: java

My system time zone is (UTC+02:00) Istanbul. When I run a simple java program to display time zone, it displays "America/Rio_Branco" (which is incorrect). But when I set to any other time zones it works correctly. Also I updated my jre using tzupdater.jar (I set my path to ..\jre\lib). What could be the reason?

My code is :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class Time
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        System.out.println("timeZone : "+timeZone);
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to provide code and also which version of jdk are you using?

Comment: are you on any kind of virtual machine / desktop ?

Comment: No, I'm not in VM. I'm running it on my laptop with with Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: You *really* don't want to be using JDK 1.5 if you want your time-zone data to be correct: it's going to be missing the last five years of time zone database updates.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced tzmappings file with the one from jre8 and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the JavaDoc you'll see this:

```
Gets the default TimeZone for this host. The source of the default TimeZone may vary with implementation.
```

Thus reason you're getting "America/Rio_Branco" is because the JDK implementation for your host (operating system) thinks you are in Rio Branco's timezone. In the comments you mention you're running Windows 7, so it might be the case that Windows incorrectly has a timezone set somewhere. I think Java on Windows checks in the registry here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/TimeZoneInformation
```

Maybe you can check that value?